# 2 different admin backends in Symfony 3 with Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Couldn't find an answer from the web, so I hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

For my pet project I want to create 3 different areas in the website.

1. Super admin backend
2. User backend
3. Frontend - which is providing a service, to which users can sign up for and then get access to "User Backend" to take advantage of the service.

I want to develop Super Admin and User backends separately. But I still want to use the Sonata Admin to build both backends.

Super admin will have its dashboard at /admin/dashboard and Users will have their dashboard at /backend/dashboard.

I have been playing around a lot with Symfony 3 and Sonata Project and I have the /admin/dashboards working together with Sonata Users Project.

But I can't seem to get /backend/dashboard link working separately from /admin/dashboard.

I have created a bundle for both /backend/dasboard and /admin/dashboard, but Sonata Admin keeps on loading Admin classes from both bundles, which it shouldn't. Also /backend path keeps on overriding /admin path. So that /admin ends up not being accessible anymore.

My best guess to solve this issue, is that I should somehow tell rounting to load different custom bundles for /backend and /admin.

Any other suggestions, how to achieve what I want?

Thanks,
Hendrik

Comment: Yes, you can separate this logic by using different Kernels to load different env/config/routing/security/bundles/etc. see https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/6840 this article in progress.

Comment: Hi Yonel, thanks for the tip, I will look into the multiple Kernel solution. :)